# Using generator to save memory

Tags: generator, python-3.5

Suppose I have one million files in my directory, It'd be a huge consumption in memory if I just did:

```
x = os.listdir('.')
```

Suppose for some reason, I chose to use os.walk method and did this to use generator:

```
def give_object(somepath)
    for x in os.walk(somepath):
        for j in x[2]:
             yield j
```

os.walk is itself a generator, and I get a value of (cur_directory, sub_directories, list_of_all_files_in_cur_directory) via x. x[2] would contain the 1 million file names. In the second for statement, I'm also yielding a value, making a generator, but, at that point, I've already created a list out from x, So, Would this code really save memory space that would be used for the 1 million items? Or is this not a correct way of using generator for the use case? If so, how should I go about doing it?